# Mirrored cache server on an EC2 Cluster?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cache, nosql

I have EC2 instances serving up a non-intensive, relatively low traffic website, and rather than shelling out for ElasticCache I was thinking of doing the caching on each server and mirroring the data in the caches.

The problem is I can't find any information on a cache server/NoSQL server that does this automatically out-of-the-box. Basically I'd like something that handles documents the same way that ElasticSearch does, where all servers on a cluster seem to get mirrored to one another very very rapidly simply by inputing the AWS credentials and having ElasticSearch perform a kind of auto-discovery to resolve the mirroring.

The web app is running on Tomcat with nginx as the web server front-end. The caches are for sections of the page, not the entire request, so the cached content would be retrieved by the web app, ideally as a JSON document. I've contemplated just using ElasticSearch for this purpose but would rather not use something not purpose-built for caching, even if ElasticSearch is relatively fast.

Comment: Why do you think you need to mirror the cache?

Comment: I have a couple of servers running on an EC2 cluster. If a request is made to one server, I want that request cached so both servers can use it. If one of the servers go down, ideally I'd like the other server to still have access to that cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can use master-slave [replication](http://redis.io/topics/replication) with Redis today. In the future, you will be able to configure a [cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec).

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into master-slave but ideally I would want to be able to read/write from both servers. I may need to look at a different piece of software, or just set up unconnected cache servers on each instance, meaning content gets cached twice, once for each server.